# Creating deployable Python builds

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Does an application to create these exist?  I'd like to be able to, in a config file / CLI / GUI (etc), to specify a version of Python and a list of libraries and for the application to then go and build me that.  I imagine it'd wrap around virtualenv.

For example:

```
[python]
    version = '3.4.1'
[libraries]
    from_pip = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib']
```

If this doesn't exist, I'll probably build something, but just want to check first.

Comment: See [`tox`](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/), possibly also [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/) or [`buildout`](http://www.buildout.org/). That aside, questions asking for tools or libraries are off-topic I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enviroment ready at the virtualenv, try `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This should create a file called requirements.txt with all packages installed by pip (you may also create this list manually).

To load from list use `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This will search and install all packages listed in that file.

Syntax is simple, you can read more about it here https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html